# very strange output with const ref initialise

Tags: c++, gcc

In one of my project, i initialized a const std::string& with a const char (know at compile time), and the result of print it was ... surprising.

I use gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)  on Ubuntu 12.04x32

Exemple:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A() : str("test"){};
    const string& str;
};

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{ 
  A a;
  cout<<a.str<<endl;
  return 0;
};
```

So, normaly, it will show "test" but, this is a prt of the output I have:

```
testP�����utf8)����lower_case_table_names�xW�xW� ��     ����127.0.0.1utf8W�Y127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP127.0.0.1
        �5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1rootW�rootW�1����metadata_use_info_schema!P�XP�� VARaءpW�P4:����SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'`(���TCP/IP (3)@!K!K!�
.....
<charset name="gb2312">
  <family>Simplified Chinese</family>
  <description>GB2312 Simplified Chinese</description>
  <alias>chinese</alias>
  <alias>iso-ir-58</alias>
   <collation name="gb2312_chinese_ci"  id="24" order="Chinese">
    <flag>primary</flag>
   <flag>compiled</flag>
  </collation>
  <collation name="gb2312_bin"  id="86">
    <flag>binary</flag>
    <flag>compiled</flag>
  </collation>
</charset>
```

the output continu for 1000 lines.

So my question is simple: WHY? (I try to add a \0 at the end of "test", but no change)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because you are dereferencing a dangling reference, which gives your program undefined behavior. Per paragraph 12.2/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the
>   constructor exits. [...]

That means the temporary `std::string` object to which `str` is bound in the constructor's initialization list will be dead by the time you dererefence `str`.

You have two ways out of this. Either make your data member `str` a `const char*`, or make it an `std::string` (not a reference type). I would personally go for the last option:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : str("test") { }
    std::string str;
};
```

Also notice, that you don't need a semicolon after *function* definitions.

Comment: @AndyProwl that's what I thought but was not really sure, I prefer to ask questions there. What amazes me is that it does not crash.

Comment: @Krozark: That is because this is undefined behavior. It may crash (it does for me) or may not (it does not for you). You can't make assumptions on a program with undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Initializing a `string &` requires a `string` and you are providing a `const char *`.  The compiler generates a temporary `string`, initializes the `string &` and then destroys the `string` leaving you with undefined behavior when you try to use the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You bind `str` reference to a temporary `std::string` that vanishes when the constructor exits.